# How to unlock Super admin account - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, admin, account

I just blocked my back office account inadvertently in Drupal 7, this account is the only super admin of my website. Is there a solution to unlock it in one way or another?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you block it? If you meant the n failed login attempts - check this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1023440

Comment: connect to your mysql and truncate `flood` table

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drush then can use 'drush uli' command. It will generate one time login link. Use that link and unblock user.
Second way can be you can update 'user' table status field to 0 to 1. (but it is hack not ideal solution)